# How to disable or override built-in functions in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

is it possible to disable built-in function such as

- attribute
- block
- constant
- cycle
- date
- dump
- include
- max
- min
- parent
- random
- range
- source
- template_from_string

Here's my code:

```
 $tags = ['if', 'for', 'set'];
 $filters = ['upper', 'escape', 'raw', 'join', 'length', 'escape'];
 $functions = ['range'];

 $policy = new \Twig_Sandbox_SecurityPolicy($tags, $filters, [], [], $functions);
```

I'm wondering why parent() can still be use when policy is allowing range only

Answer (score 2):

`parent()` is not a function, this is a language construct (just like `isset()` in php).

Consider the following code:

<kbd>main.twig</kbd>

```
{% extends 'parent.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ max(1, 2, 3) }}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

<kbd>parent.twig</kbd>

```
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
```

If you look at the compiled template, the body block will be compiled like this:

```
    // line 3
    public function block_body($context, array $blocks = array())
    {
        // line 4
        echo "
    ";
        // line 5
        echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, max(1, 2, 3), "html", null, true);
        echo "

    ";
        // line 7
        $this->displayParentBlock("body", $context, $blocks);
        echo "

";
    }
```

If you want to look at the [full compiled template](https://twigfiddle.com/h3f6t4).

As you can see, Twig doesn't call this function using the standard helpers, and thus, `parent()` does not go through the sandbox filtering system.

If you want another proof that `parent()` is a language construct, just call it when you're not in a `block()`. You'll get a `Twig_Error_Syntax` exception, not a `Twig_Error_Runtime` one. [Try it yourself in this fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/16fyxg).

So to answer your question, the only way to disable `parent()` is to disable the `{% block %}` tag. And thus, using `parent()` will throw a syntax error, just like a forgotten `%}` would do.